# Самые короткие и простые способы генерации различных фракталов или других изображений

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика, canvas, webgl

Я интересуюсь компьютерной графикой и хотел бы провести своего рода конкурс.

Я хотел бы узнать о новых (для себя) способах генерации различных фракталов или других изображений, полученных по достаточно простой формуле.

**То есть критерием соревнования является, - использование простой базовой формулы для получения интересных  картинок.**

---

Например есть такая реализация цикла по всем пикселям на картинке:

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height  

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, m) => {
    return [x/w+cx/w, y/h+cy/h, 0]
}

canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            let value = formula(x, y, e.x, e.y)
            let offset = (y*w + x)*4    
            img.data[offset]     = value[0]*255
            img.data[offset + 1] = value[1]*255
            img.data[offset + 2] = value[2]*255
            img.data[offset + 3] = 255
        }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}

canvas.onmousemove({x: 456, y: 123})
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>
```

Необходимо реализовать функцию `formula` для получения "интересного" изображения, дополнительными аргументами выступают координаты мыши

Язык - любой, но желательно `js`, из-за возможности онлайн визуализации.

PS: рекурсивные методы мне менее интересны, особенно если рекурсия не хвостовая, так какпортировать это на glsl будет сложно если не невозможно.

P.P.S. для привлечения более широкой аудитории мной был выбран cpu  и код цикла по картинке я написал для него, однако если Вам угодно, мне больше импонирует webgl, по этому ниже сниппет, где цикл по всем пикселям делает видеокарта, когда я рисую один треугольник, закрывающий весь экран, а функция formula - это фрагментный шейдер :)

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader('vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader('fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let coords = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);

let mouse = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mouse');
let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

let changeCenter = e => {
  e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
  gl.uniform2f(mouse, e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
  draw();
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', changeCenter);
window.addEventListener('touchmove', changeCenter);

draw();

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl/${src}"]`).textContent);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
      return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
    }).join('\n'));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>

<script type="glsl/vertex">

attribute vec2 coords;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}

</script>

<script type="glsl/fragment">

precision highp float;

uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {
    vec2 m = mouse/resolution;
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution - 0.5;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(p, m); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: а кто-то кроме вас участвует? =)

Comment: @Anatol пока нет, но я искренне надеюсь что будут =)

Comment: связанный ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985757/188366

Comment: я как будто под ЛСД когда смотрю на все эти фотки

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов нередко психические расстройства и прием психостумуляторов порождает узоры, похожие на фракталы, наверняка есть прямая связь между тем как устроена природа(мозг) и фракталами

Comment: @StrangerintheQ наверное будет медалька за отличный вопрос

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а за что ее дают?, не нашел в описаниях

Comment: @StrangerintheQ на память надеюсь, но проверю - серебряная за  25++

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ах за голоса, ну да, спасибо, кстати вот пен по теме топика =) https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/WNrXLPV

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  отличный пень!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Пример с [бассейном Ньютона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Области подкрашиваются в соответствии с близостью к корням уравнения *z<sup>3</sup>-1 = 0*

```js
class Complex {
  constructor({algebraic,trigonometric} = {}) {
    if (algebraic) {
      this.initAlgebraic(algebraic);
    } else if (trigonometric) {
      this.initTrigonometric(trigonometric)
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid arguments');
    }
  }
  static fromReal(r) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(r, 0);
  }
  static fromAlgebraic(r, i) {
    return new Complex({algebraic: {r,i}});
  }
  static fromTrigonometric(modulus, arg) {
    return new Complex({trigonometric: {modulus,arg}});
  }

  initAlgebraic({r,i}) {
    this.r = r;
    this.i = i;
    this.modulus = Math.sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    this.arg = Math.atan2(i, r)
  }
  initTrigonometric({modulus,arg}) {
    this.modulus = modulus,
    this.arg = arg;
    this.r = this.modulus * Math.cos(arg);
    this.i = this.modulus * Math.sin(arg);
  }
  pow(exp) {
    return Complex.fromTrigonometric(Math.pow(this.modulus, exp), exp * this.arg);
  }
  add(c) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r + c.r, this.i + c.i);
  }
  conjugate(){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r, -this.i);
  }
  sub(c){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r - c.r, this.i - c.i);
  }
  mul(c){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r*c.r-this.i*c.i, this.r*c.i+this.i*c.r);
  }
  div(c){
   var cConjugate = c.conjugate();
    var mulToConjugate = this.mul(cConjugate);
    var divider = c.mul(cConjugate).r;
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(mulToConjugate.r/divider, mulToConjugate.i/divider);
  }
}
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height 
function formula(x,y, maxIter, max, min){
  var z = Complex.fromAlgebraic(x,y);
  var d = z;
  for(var i=0;i<maxIter && z.modulus<max && d.modulus>min;i++){
    var z1 = z.sub(z.pow(3).add(Complex.fromReal(-1)).div(z.pow(2).mul(Complex.fromReal(3))));
    //var z1 = z.sub(z.pow(5).add(Complex.fromReal(-1)).div(z.pow(4).mul(Complex.fromReal(5))));
    var z2 = z1.sub(z);
    d = Complex.fromAlgebraic(Math.abs(z2.r),Math.abs(z2.i));
    z = z1;
  }
  return [i, z];
}
var input = document.getElementById('coef');
input.addEventListener('change',function(){
  draw(this.value);
});
var roots = [
Complex.fromReal(1),
Complex.fromAlgebraic(-1, Math.sqrt(3)/2),
Complex.fromAlgebraic(-1, -Math.sqrt(3)/2),
]
var maxDistance = input.max;
function draw(distance){
    var xc = w/2;
    var yc = h/2;
    var coef = 0.0015 + distance * ((0.015-0.0015)/maxDistance);
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    var aaa = 0;
    for(var y = -h/2; y<h/2; y++) {
      for(var x = -w/2; x<w/2; x++) {
        let [value,root] = formula(x*coef, y*coef, 50,1e6, 1e-6);
        
        
        let offset = ((y+yc)*w + x+xc)*4 
        img.data[offset]     = (value*roots[0].sub(root).modulus*7)%255;
        img.data[offset + 1] = (value*roots[1].sub(root).modulus*5)%255;
        img.data[offset + 2] = (value*roots[2].sub(root).modulus*11)%255;
        img.data[offset + 3] = 255
      }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) ;
};
draw(100);
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" min="0" max="200" id="coef" value="100">
```

Для урaвнения *z<sup>5</sup>-1 = 0*

```js
class Complex {
  constructor({algebraic,trigonometric} = {}) {
    if (algebraic) {
      this.initAlgebraic(algebraic);
    } else if (trigonometric) {
      this.initTrigonometric(trigonometric)
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid arguments');
    }
  }
  static fromReal(r) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(r, 0);
  }
  static fromAlgebraic(r, i) {
    return new Complex({algebraic: {r,i}});
  }
  static fromTrigonometric(modulus, arg) {
    return new Complex({trigonometric: {modulus,arg}});
  }

  initAlgebraic({r,i}) {
    this.r = r;
    this.i = i;
    this.modulus = Math.sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    this.arg = Math.atan2(i, r)
  }
  initTrigonometric({modulus,arg}) {
    this.modulus = modulus,
    this.arg = arg;
    this.r = this.modulus * Math.cos(arg);
    this.i = this.modulus * Math.sin(arg);
  }
  pow(exp) {
    return Complex.fromTrigonometric(Math.pow(this.modulus, exp), exp * this.arg);
  }
  add(c) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r + c.r, this.i + c.i);
  }
  conjugate(){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r, -this.i);
  }
  sub(c){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r - c.r, this.i - c.i);
  }
  mul(c){
   return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r*c.r-this.i*c.i, this.r*c.i+this.i*c.r);
  }
  div(c){
   var cConjugate = c.conjugate();
    var mulToConjugate = this.mul(cConjugate);
    var divider = c.mul(cConjugate).r;
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(mulToConjugate.r/divider, mulToConjugate.i/divider);
  }
}
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height 
function formula(x,y, maxIter, max, min){
  var z = Complex.fromAlgebraic(x,y);
  var d = z;
  for(var i=0;i<maxIter && z.modulus<max && d.modulus>min;i++){
    //var z1 = z.sub(z.pow(3).add(Complex.fromReal(-1)).div(z.pow(2).mul(Complex.fromReal(3))));
    var z1 = z.sub(z.pow(5).add(Complex.fromReal(-1)).div(z.pow(4).mul(Complex.fromReal(5))));
    var z2 = z1.sub(z);
    d = Complex.fromAlgebraic(Math.abs(z2.r),Math.abs(z2.i));
    z = z1;
  }
  return [i, z];
}
var input = document.getElementById('coef');
input.addEventListener('change',function(){
  draw(this.value);
});

var maxDistance = input.max;
function draw(distance){
    var xc = w/2;
    var yc = h/2;
    var coef = 0.0015 + distance * ((0.015-0.0015)/maxDistance);
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    var aaa = 0;
    for(var y = -h/2; y<h/2; y++) {
      for(var x = -w/2; x<w/2; x++) {
        let [value,root] = formula(x*coef, y*coef, 50,1e6, 1e-6);       
        
        let offset = ((y+yc)*w + x+xc)*4 
        img.data[offset]     = (value*7)%255;
        img.data[offset + 1] = (value*5)%255;
        img.data[offset + 2] = (value*11)%255;
        img.data[offset + 3] = 255
      }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) ;
};
draw(100);
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" id="coef" value="100">
```

Comment: я выбрал этот ответ, потому что этот фрактал еще не реализовывал и пока не думал даже об этом =)

Answer (score 18):

Предлагаю Вашему вниманию **Суперформулу**

Суперформула является обобщением суперэллипса и впервые была  выведена Йоханом Гиелисом в 2003 году. Гиелис предположил использовать формулу для описания сложных форм и кривых, которые встречаются в природе.

В [полярной системе координат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82), с [image: введите сюда описание изображения] радиусом, и [image: введите сюда описание изображения]  углом, суперформула выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбирая различные значения параметров [image: введите сюда описание изображения], получаются различные формы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height  

 // функция возвращает расстояние в полярной системе координат для угла phi, идущего первым аргументом
function superformula(phi, m,  n1, a, b, n2, n3) {
    with (Math) {
        m = m*phi/4;
        a = pow(abs(cos(m))/a, n2);
        b = pow(abs(sin(m))/b, n3);
        return pow(a + b, -1/n1);
    }
}

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy) => {
    x = (2*x-w)/w*(3-cy/h);
    y = (2*y-h)/w*(3-cy/h);
    let a = Math.atan2(y, x) - cx/w*Math.PI;
    let d = superformula(a, t.m, t.n1, t.a, t.b, t.n2, t.n3);
    let l = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    let c = Math.min(d-l)*10.;
    return [c, c, c]
}

let types = {
  asterisk: {m: 12, n1: .3, n2: 0, n3: 10, a: 1, b: 1},
  bean: {m: 2, n1: 1, n2: 4, n3: 8, a: 1, b: 1},
  butterfly: {m: 3, n1: 1, n2: 6, n3: 2, a: .6, b: 1},
  circle: {m: 4, n1: 2, n2: 2, n3: 2, a: 1, b: 1},
  clover: {m: 6, n1: .3, n2: 0, n3: 10, a: 1, b: 1},
  cloverFour: {m: 8, n1: 10, n2: -1, n3: -8, a: 1, b: 1},
  cross: {m: 8, n1: 1.3, n2: .01, n3: 8, a: 1, b: 1},
  diamond: {m: 4, n1: 1, n2: 1, n3: 1, a: 1, b: 1},
  drop: {m: 1, n1: .5, n2: .5, n3: .5, a: 1, b: 1},
  gear: {m: 19, n1: 100, n2: 50, n3: 50, a: 1, b: 1},
  heart: {m: 1, n1: .8, n2: 1, n3: -8, a: 1, b: .18},
  heptagon: {m: 7, n1: 1000, n2: 400, n3: 400, a: 1, b: 1},
  hexagon: {m: 6, n1: 1000, n2: 400, n3: 400, a: 1, b: 1},
  malteseCross: {m: 8, n1: .9, n2: .1, n3: 100, a: 1, b: 1},
  pentagon: {m: 5, n1: 1000, n2: 600, n3: 600, a: 1, b: 1},
  rectangle: {m: 4, n1: 100, n2: 100, n3: 100, a: 2, b: 1},
  roundedStar: {m: 5, n1: 2, n2: 7, n3: 7, a: 1, b: 1},
  square: {m: 4, n1: 100, n2: 100, n3: 100, a: 1, b: 1},
  star: {m: 5, n1: 30, n2: 100, n3: 100, a: 1, b: 1},
  triangle: {m: 3, n1: 100, n2: 200, n3: 200, a: 1, b: 1}
};

let t = Object.values(types)[0];

let draw = e => {
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            let value = formula(x, y, e.x, e.y)
            let offset = (y*w + x)*4    
            img.data[offset]     = value[0]*255
            img.data[offset + 1] = value[1]*255
            img.data[offset + 2] = value[2]*255
            img.data[offset + 3] = 255
        }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}

draw({x:100, y:100})

canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    draw(e);
}

canvas.onclick = e => {
  let vals = Object.values(types);
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*vals.length);
  t = vals[i];
  document.querySelector('span').textContent = 'click to change: ' + Object.keys(types)[i]
  draw(e)
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0;user-select:none"><canvas width="175" height="175" id="canvas"></canvas><br><span>click to change: asterisk</span></body>
```

Answer (score 15):

Самое простое что известно мне, помимо фракталов в комплексной плоскости - это фрактал `kali`, назван в честь опубликовавшего [эту формулу на fractalforums](http://www.fractalforums.com/new-theories-and-research/very-simple-formula-for-fractal-patterns/)

формула в glsl для него вообще простая:

```
vec2 q = vec2(x, y);
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
  q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) - vec2(cx, cy);
```

на `js` чуть посложнее из-за отсутствия операций над векторами, но все равно очень простая:

```
let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, m) => {
    x = (2*x-w)/w;
    y = (2*y-h)/w;
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        x = Math.abs(x)
        y = Math.abs(y)
        m = x*x + y*y
        x = x/m - cx/w
        y = y/m - cy/h
    }
    return [x, y, Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)/2.]
}
```

---

Вот результат для cpu версии, мышка меняет переменные в формуле для получения другого изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height  

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, m) => {
    x = (2*x-w)/w;
    y = (2*y-h)/w;
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        x = Math.abs(x)
        y = Math.abs(y)
        m = x*x + y*y
        x = x/m - cx/w
        y = y/m - cy/h
    }
    return [x, y, Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)/2.]
}

canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            let value = formula(x, y, e.x, e.y)
            let offset = (y*w + x)*4    
            img.data[offset]     = value[0]*255
            img.data[offset + 1] = value[1]*255
            img.data[offset + 2] = value[2]*255
            img.data[offset + 3] = 255
        }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}

canvas.onmousemove({x: 456, y: 123})
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>
```

---

GPU вариация и другая палитра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader('vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader('fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let coords = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);

let mouse = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mouse');
let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

let changeCenter = e => {
  e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
  gl.uniform2f(mouse, e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
  draw();
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', changeCenter);
window.addEventListener('touchmove', changeCenter);

draw();

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl/${src}"]`).textContent);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
      return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
    }).join('\n'));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>

<script type="glsl/vertex">

attribute vec2 coords;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}

</script>

<script type="glsl/fragment">

precision highp float;

uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {

    vec2 m = mouse/resolution;
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    
    // вот собственно сама формула реализована в этих 3 строчках
    vec2 q = (p + p - resolution) / resolution.y;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  m;
         
         
    gl_FragColor = vec4(q, q.x/q.y, 1.0);
}

</script>
```

---

Еще одна вариация фрактала

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader('vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader('fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let coords = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);

let mouse = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mouse');
let resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'resolution');
gl.uniform2f(resolution, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

let changeCenter = e => {
  e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
  gl.uniform2f(mouse, e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
  draw();
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', changeCenter);
window.addEventListener('touchmove', changeCenter);

draw();

function draw() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, document.querySelector(`script[type="glsl/${src}"]`).textContent);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
      return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
    }).join('\n'));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="175" id="canvas"/>

<script type="glsl/vertex">

attribute vec2 coords;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}

</script>

<script type="glsl/fragment">

precision highp float;

uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void) {

    vec2 m = mouse/resolution;
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    
    // вот собственно сама формула реализована в этих 3 строчках
    vec2 q = (p + p - resolution) / resolution.y/m.y;
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
         q = -abs(q)/dot(q,q) + m;
         
         
    gl_FragColor = vec4(q, 1.-dot(q,q), 1.0);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Поздравляю с очередным достижением 20.000!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Ваши? премного благодарен =)

Comment: крутая штука ))) способ залипнуть на минут 15

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц вот мой snadbox для залипания https://tinyurl.com/y2pspcxd

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц https://tinyurl.com/y3wr3xlj

Answer (score 13):

[Множество Жюлиа (Julia set)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%96%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0)

Формула для него  выглядит вот так:

[image: z] где `z` это комплексное число:

В этом примере значение `c` зависит от координат мышки, что позволяет одновременно наблюдать великое множество различных изображений множества Жюлиа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все эти изображения получены при помощи нижеприведенного сниппета с минимальными изменениями

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height  

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, m) => {
  let z = [(2*y-h)/w*1.5,(2*x-w)/w*1.5];  
  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {  
    z = [ z[0] * z[0] - z[1] * z[1] + cy/h, 2. * z[0] * z[1] + cx/w]; 
    if (z[0]*z[0] + z[1]*z[1] > 4.) 
      return i; 
  }
  return 0
}

canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
            let v = formula(x, y, e.x, e.y)
            let o = (y*w + x)*4    
            img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/5)*255
            img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/6)*255
            img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/7)*255
            img.data[o++] = 255
        }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}

canvas.onmousemove({x: 111, y: 123})
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"/>
```

По очень похожей  формуле получается обобщение всех множеств Жюлиа - [Множество Мандельброта (Mandelbrot set)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

[Сетка Аполлона.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  w = canvas.width,
  h = canvas.height;

var x = 0.2,
  y = 0.3,
  a = 0,
  b = 0,
  r = Math.sqrt(3),
  points = Array(1000),
  counter = 0;

(function starter() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(starter);
}())

function sqr(x) {
  return x * x;
}

function putPixels(x, y) {
  var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
  let offset = (y * w + x) * 4;
  img.data[offset] = 255;
  img.data[offset + 1] = 0;
  img.data[offset + 2] = 0;
  img.data[offset + 3] = 255;
  c.putImageData(img, 0, 0)
}

function draw() {
  a = Math.random();
  var div = sqr(1 + r - x) + sqr(y);
  var a0 = 3 * (1 + r - x) / (div) - (1 + r) / (2 + r);
  var b0 = 3 * y / (div);
  if (a <= 1 / 3 && a >= 0) {
    x1 = a0;
    y1 = b0;
  } else {
    var a1 = -1 / 2;
    var b1 = r / 2;
    var a2 = -1 / 2;
    var b2 = -r / 2;
    var d =sqr(a0) + sqr(b0);
    var f1x = a0 / (d);
    var f1y = -b0 / (d);

    if (a <= 2 / 3 && a > 1 / 3) {
      x1 = f1x * a1 - f1y * b1;
      y1 = f1x * b1 + f1y * a1;
    }
    if (a <= 3 / 3 && a > 2 / 3) {
      x1 = f1x * a2 - f1y * b2;
      y1 = f1x * b2 + f1y * a2;
    }
  }
  x = x1;
  y = y1;
  putPixels(320 + x * 50 | 0, 240 + y * 50 | 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="650" height="500" id="canvas" />
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо, за объяснениями в гугл или у Вас есть какая-то ссылочка?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ. добавил ссылку на википедию. Код в принципе переписан с pascal [отсюда](http://grafika.me/node/360). Но очень долго рисуется вероятно из-за того что random иногда в себя попадает. А через построение кругов, а не поточечно не осилил :-)

Comment: визуально похоже на метод хаоса для построения треугольника серпинского : https://elementy.ru/posters/fractals/Sierpinski

Comment: `На плоскости зафиксирован правильный треугольник A1A2A3. Отмечают любую начальную точку B0. Затем случайным образом выбирают одну из трех вершин треугольника и отмечают точку B1 — середину отрезка с концами в этой вершине и в B0 (на рисунке справа случайно выбралась вершина A1). То же самое повторяют с точкой B1, чтобы получить B2. Потом получают точки B3, B4, и т. д. Важно, чтобы точка «прыгала» случайным образом, независимо от того, что было выбрано в предыдущие шаги. Удивительно, что если отмечать точки из последовательности Bi, то вскоре начнет проступать треугольник Серпинского. `

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да, я так понял они по одному принципу просто у Серпинского треугольники, а тут окружности

Comment: Метод конечно странный, так получилось что тоже совсем недавно о нем узнал, не о фрактале а о методе.

Comment: попробовал исключать повторы - не сильно помогло

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я тоже пробовал, мне кажется там еще дольше получается :-)

Comment: удаленный ответ - я не понял в чем отличие но оно есть, это множество жюлиа, только степень четвератя а не вторая на каждой итерации https://tinyurl.com/y3pewru6

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94239/discussion-between-grundy-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 6):

При возведении комплексного аргумента в 4 степень можно получить фрактал по форме напоминающий живой организм, такие фракталы называют биоморфами.

```js
class Complex {
  constructor({algebraic,trigonometric} = {}) {
    if (algebraic) {
      this.initAlgebraic(algebraic);
    } else if (trigonometric) {
      this.initTrigonometric(trigonometric)
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid arguments');
    }
  }
  static fromReal(r) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(r, 0);
  }
  static fromAlgebraic(r, i) {
    return new Complex({algebraic: {r,i}});
  }
  static fromTrigonometric(modulus, arg) {
    return new Complex({trigonometric: {modulus,arg}});
  }

  initAlgebraic({r,i}) {
    this.r = r;
    this.i = i;
    this.modulus = Math.sqrt(r * r + i * i);
    this.arg = Math.atan2(i, r)
  }
  initTrigonometric({modulus,arg}) {
    this.modulus = modulus,
    this.arg = arg;
    this.r = this.modulus * Math.cos(arg);
    this.i = this.modulus * Math.sin(arg);
  }
  pow(exp) {
    return Complex.fromTrigonometric(Math.pow(this.modulus, exp), exp * this.arg);
  }
  add(c) {
    return Complex.fromAlgebraic(this.r + c.r, this.i + c.i);
  }
}
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height 
function formula(x,y,cx,cy, maxIter){
  var z = Complex.fromAlgebraic(x,y);
  var c = Complex.fromAlgebraic(cx,cy);
  for(var i=0;i<maxIter || z.modulus<50;i++){
    z = z.pow(4).add(c);
    if(Math.abs(z.r) > 10 || Math.abs(z.i) > 1000) {
    return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
canvas.onmousemove = e => {
    var xc = w/2;
    var yc = h/2;
    var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
    for(var y = -h/2; y<h/2; y++) {
      for(var x = -w/2; x<w/2; x++) {
        let value = formula(x*0.01, y*0.01, e.x/399, 1+e.y/398, 70)
        let offset = ((y+yc)*w + x+xc)*4 
        img.data[offset]     = Math.sin(value)*255;
        img.data[offset + 1] = Math.cos(value)*255;
        img.data[offset + 2] = Math.random()*value*255;
        img.data[offset + 3] = 255
      }
    }
    c.putImageData(img, 0, 0) 
}
console.log(1);
canvas.onmousemove({x: 111, y: 123})
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"/>
```

Comment: спасибо, это вариация множества Жюлиа, попробую попозже подправить палитру

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, на сколько я понял Жюлиа - это только вторая степень, но могу ошибаться

Comment: множество Жюлиа образуется когда к базовой формуле на каждой итерации прибавляется какая-то константа, а не значение текущего пикселя.

Comment: 2 степерь это множество жюлиа для множества мандельброта, для любого фрактала в комплексном пространстве, даже трехмерного есть соответствующее бесконечное множество множеств жюлиа

Comment: https://strangerintheq.github.io/mandelbulb-julia.html

Comment: по ссылке - множество жюлиа для mandelbulb, сама бульба почему-то не работает, сломал

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/yWxqqB вот Ваш фрактал, я там немного подправил код выхода из цикла и добавил `c1`, попробуйте его добавить в итерации а не `c` и появится обобщение всех этих множеств жюлиа - множество мандельброта только не с 1 бульбой а с 3мя =)

Comment: дальнейшее возведение в степень добавляет еще малые пузыри

Comment: выход из цикла можно проверять по условию что точка отлетела от центра больше чем пороговое расстояние 2, по теореме пифагора `z.r*z*r+z.i*z.i > 2*2`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, `z.r*z*r+z.i*z.i` - Это модуль комплексного числа :-) он в отдельном поле у меня хранится :-)

Comment: Добавил ответ с горящим кораблём, потом сделаю интерактивную версию чтобы можно было передвигаться вглубь

Answer (score 4):

В продолжение темы фракталов в комплексной плоскости - вариация множества Мандельброта, но в каждой итерации компоненты комплексного `z` берутся по модулю - имеет название [Burning Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Ship_fractal), за визуальную похожесть деталей фрактала на корабль. Интересен очень высокой вариативностью геометрических узоров при большом увеличении.

```
   ...
z[0] = Math.abs(z[0]);
z[1] = Math.abs(z[1]);
   ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если приближаться в район мачт кораблей можно найти интересные участки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w=canvas.width, h=canvas.height, cx=0, cy=0, z=0.25;  

let formula = (x, y, cx, cy, it) => {
  let z = [0,0];  
  for (var i = 0; i < it; ++i) {  
    z[0] = Math.abs(z[0]);
    z[1] = Math.abs(z[1]);
    z = [ z[0] * z[0] - z[1] * z[1] - x+cx, 2. * z[0] * z[1] + y-cy]; 
    if (z[0]*z[0] + z[1]*z[1] > 4.1) 
      return i; 
  }
  return 0
}

let p, ct;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
  p = {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY};
  ct = {x:cx, y:cy};
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
  if (!p) return;
  cx = ct.x + (e.pageX - p.x)/w/z;
  cy = ct.y + (e.pageY - p.y)/h/z;
  render()
})

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
  p = null
})

canvas.addEventListener('wheel',function(e){
  z *= 1 + Math.sign(e.wheelDeltaY)*0.1
  e.preventDefault();
  render()
})
render()

function render() {
  let red = r.value;
  let green = g.value;
  let blue = b.value;
  let it = iter.value;
  var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
  for(var x = 0; x<w; x++) {
      for(var y = 0; y<h; y++) {
          let v = formula((x/w-0.5)/z, (y/h-0.5)/z,cx,cy,it)
          let o = (y*w + x)*4    
          img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/red)*255
          img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/green)*255
          img.data[o++] = Math.sin(v/blue)*255
          img.data[o++] = 255
      }
  }
  c.putImageData(img, 0, 0)
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="iter" min=16 max=512 value=32 onchange="render()"/>
<input type="range" id="r" min=1 max=33 value=11 onchange="render()"/>
<input type="range" id="g" min=1 max=33 value=7 onchange="render()" />
<input type="range" id="b" min=1 max=33 value=22 onchange="render()" />
<br>
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"/>
```

PS: В сниппете работает колесо мышки и драг, при помощи слайдеров можно поменять кол-во итерация и палитру

Comment: посмотрел я все примеры и так и не понял куда это всё применять ? какие то без форменные объекты ...

Comment: @MaximLensky не во всем прекрасном есть практический смысл...

Comment: @MaximLensky посмотрите "Доктора Стренджа"

Comment: @MaximLensky если Вам действительно интересно  - фракталы и фрактальные алгоритмы нашли много применения в компьютерной графике и геймдеве, - многие природные объекты (облака, деревья, горы, реки) - фракталы, и для их программной генерации хорошо подходят фрактальные алгоримты. но это мало соотносится конкретно с этими изображеними. эти изображения - прекрасны с точки зрения математики т.к. имеют очень простые базовые формулы и генерируют бесконечное множество интересных узоров - своего рода арт объекты

Comment: @MaximLensky так же существуют например фрактальные алгоритмы сжатия изображений https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: я это понял ...но так же я понял что я далёк от Квадрата Малевича ... и импресионистов ...:))

Answer (score 3):

[Фрактал Ляпунова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB_%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

> Фракталы Ляпунова строятся отображением областей стабильного и хаотического поведения, измеряемых экспонентой Ляпунова, в плоскости a-b для данной периодической последовательности a и b.

Форма зависит от введенной строки включающей символы `A` и `B`, а так же от выбранного квадрата в диапазоне [0x4, 0x4]

Приведенный пример с конкретными параметрами также известен как Zircon City.

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  w = canvas.width,
  h = canvas.height
var i = 0;

function formula(a, b, N, S) {
  var xn = 0.5;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var n = 1; n < N; n++) {
    var rn = S[n % S.length] == 'A' ? a : b;
    xn = rn * xn * (1 - xn);
    sum += Math.log2(Math.abs(rn * (1 - 2 * xn)));

    if (sum > 10000) return 50;
    if (sum < -10000) return -50;
  }
  return sum / N;
}

function getRect() {
  var xmin = +document.getElementById('xmin').value;
  var xmax = +document.getElementById('xmax').value;
  var ymin = +document.getElementById('ymin').value;
  var ymax = +document.getElementById('ymax').value;

  return [{
    start: Math.min(xmin, xmax),
    range: Math.abs(xmax - xmin) / w
  }, {
    start: Math.min(ymin, ymax),
    range: Math.abs(ymax - ymin) / h
  }];
}

function draw() {
  var img = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h)
  var S = document.getElementById('S').value;
  var [p1, p2] = getRect();
  for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
      let La = formula(p1.start + x * p1.range, p2.start + y * p2.range, 1000, S);
      let offset = ((h - y) * w + x) * 4
      if (La > 0) {
        img.data[offset] = (La * 25 + 10) % 256;
        img.data[offset + 1] = (La * 25 + 10) % 216;
      } else {
        img.data[offset] = 255 - (-La * 20 + 50) % 256
        img.data[offset + 1] = 215 - (-La * 20 + 50) % 216
      }
      img.data[offset + 2] = 0
      img.data[offset + 3] = 255

    }
  }
  c.putImageData(img, 0, 0)
}

draw();
```

```css
#c {
  display: flex;
}
#settings{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <div>
    <canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="settings">
    <label>xmin <input type="number" id="xmin" min="0" max="4" step="0.1" value="2.5"/></label>
    <label>xmax <input type="number" id="xmax" min="0" max="4" step="0.1" value="3.4"/></label><br>
    <label>ymin <input type="number" id="ymin" min="0" max="4" step="0.1" value="3.4"/></label>
    <label>ymax <input type="number" id="ymax" min="0" max="4" step="0.1" value="4"/></label><br>
    <label>Seq <input type="text" id="S" value="BBBBBBAAAAAA"/></label>
    <input type="button" value="apply" onclick="draw()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, это очень интересная штука, но её колоризация похоже будет болью, попробую на досуге

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, во всех описаниях: цвет в зависимости от значения экспоненты Ляпунова, но саму зависимость нигде не указывают :)

Answer (score 1):

1)Модификация кривой Леви.

Посмотрите тут новые фракталы, модификация кривой Леви, есть онлайн построение. Формула одна меняется только кол-во углов. Скорей это уже больше L системы.
https://habr.com/ru/post/328568/

2).Странные  аттракторы с симметрией.

Обычно странные аттракторы бесформенная каша пикселей или траекторий, тут фотки как из хаоса можно получить симметрию. Вроде в той проге и коды есть…да и pdf можно нагуглить при желании.
http://www.fractalsciencekit.com/tutorial/examples/symicon.htm

3). Снежинки из параметрических кривых Безье.

Формы и сложность можно создать бесконечную. Суть формула одна и также только разное количество кривых и координат опорных точек. Вот тут делал давно на GeoGebra 5.
https://www.cyberforum.ru/mathcad/thread1271478.html#post6735492

Там еще где-то в теме была ссылка люди скидывали параметрические уравнения рисующие сложные цветки, форма менялась от параметров.
Вот эти делал.
https://www.cyberforum.ru/mathcad/thread1271478-page2.html#post6766654

4)Вообще по фракталам

Есть прога Fractal Science Kit, не видел больше нигде такого количества всяких таких штук, несколько сотен наверно с настройками.

5)Новый алгоритм генерации типа снежинок или лабиринтов.

Вот тут  случайно открыл новый алгоритм генерации типа снежинок или лабиринтов, алгоритм чем-то похоже на игру жизнь.
Делал реакцию диффузии и алгоритмически ошибся =). Получилось интересно. Можно генерировать всякие узоры типа вышиванки крестиком, алгоритм останавливает граница в 1 пиксель. Рост начинается с 1 пикселя.
Вот тут делал 5 анимаций, а код  там есть в теме чего-то вылетает после компиляции =(. Делал вроде на старом glut.
https://www.cyberforum.ru/opengl/thread2749102-page3.html#post15131849

Вспомнил еще два новых для меня метода, насколько помню почти не упомянуты в литературе по фракталам.

6)Chaos_game.

Недавно для себя открыл метод, еще ничего с ним не пробовал. По идее потенциал огромен.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game

7)Cyclic Symmetric Multi-Scale Turing Patterns
Новый для меня алгоритм основан на реакции диффузии. Собственно для нее я и хотел подойти сделав базовую диффузию из 5 пункта. Пока энтузиазм подугас. Но рисует там очень необычно, как фотки с электронного микроскопа.