# как создать canvas с градиентом

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

Ка сделать так чтобы по ид создавались новые canvas в зависимости от текста
то есть
Внутри canvas прозрачный цвет только граница с градиентом нужна

```html
<button type="submit" id="can-img">Кнопка</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy как такое изображение в канвас получить

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте покрасим каждый пиксель сами, для этого используем математику и прямые манипуляции с с пикселями, такой подход позволяет очень точно посчитать различные эффекты, сложно достижимые при обычном рисовании встроенными методами.

Я недавно задавал  [вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983698/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0) на этот счет, в этом примере применен тот же подход:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

^^ **это анимированный гиф, хоть и не заметно почти**

---

Пару слов о том как это работает.

[**Signed Distance Function(или Field)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) - это такой механизм определения **минимального** расстояния до **ближайшего** объекта сцены.

SDF может быть задан формулами или массивом значений расстояний (обычно это один канал текстуры)

Вот пример изображения с sdf для звезды, это по сути обрамляющий градиент вокруг фигуры

[image]

Теперь, используя цикл по всем пикселям и не хитрые вычисления мы определяем как красить каждый пиксель в зависимости от его расстояния до фигуры.

В коде ниже использована формула, которая возвращает расстояние до скругленного прямоугольника. [Больше формул тут](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm). Формулы эти можно всячески комбинировать и использовать получившуюся функцию для получения изображения объектов, (не обязательно в 2d, так же можно получать изображения 3d объектов [используя SDF и трассировку лучей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/927012#927012))

```js
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'), w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height   
 
requestAnimationFrame(draw) 
 
function draw(t) {  
  let i = c.getImageData(0, 0, w, h) 
  // цикл по всем пикселям 
  for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) { 
  for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) { 
      let v = px(x, y, t) 
      let o = (y*w + x)*4     
      i.data[o++] = v[0]*255 
      i.data[o++] = v[1]*255 
      i.data[o++] = v[2]*255 
      i.data[o++] = v[3]*255 
  }} 
  c.putImageData(i, 0, 0) 
  requestAnimationFrame(draw) 
} 
 
// функция дистанции до скругленного прямоугольника 
// https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm 
function sdRoundBox(x, y, sx, sy, r) { 
  x = Math.abs(x) - sx; 
  y = Math.abs(y) - sy; 
  sx = Math.max(x, 0);  
  sy = Math.max(y, 0); 
  return Math.min(Math.max(x, y), 0) + Math.sqrt(sx*sx + sy*sy) - r; 
} 
 
// функция которая определяет цвет пикселя 
function px(x, y, t) { 
  // определим минимальное расстояние от текущего пикселя до нашей фигуры 
  let d = Math.abs(sdRoundBox(2*x-w, 2*y-h, 150, 40, 15)); 
  if (d>16) return [0, 0, 0, 0] 
  // и используем это расстояние и координату пикселя по х для определения цвета пикселя 
  let c = Math.min(d/32 + 0.3 + Math.sin(t/1000)*0.1, d/8); 
  return [0.4+(x/w+1-y/h)*0.3, c, 1, 1-c]; 
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="100" id="canvas"/>
```

Comment: забыл написать - это медленный способ, и мне кажется тут можно было использовать тень.

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать градиент с помощью функции [ctx.createLinearGradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient)

Пример кода:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//создаем градиент
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(20, 0, 220, 0);

//добавляем три точки остановки
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop(.5, 'cyan');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green');

//рисуем контур прямоугольника с помощью ерадиента
ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 200, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Функция `ctx.createLinearGradient()` принимает четыре аргумента:

x0 - Координата по оси X начальной точки.
y0 - Координата по оси Y начальной точки.
x1 - Координата по оси X конечной точки.
y1 - Координата по оси Y конечной точки.

Чтобы задать точки останова используется функция `gradient.addColorStop();`, принимающая два параметра: первый - смещение от начала градиента  (не должен выходить за пределы 0 - 1), где будет расположена точка останова, второй - цвет до которого дойдет градиент в этой точке останова.

Comment: а можете пример кода показать

Comment: @Vadim принажатии на имя функции вас перекинет на сайт, на котором есть пример. Ссылка на тот сайт: [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient)