# Закруглить края у canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Есть код как тут закруглить края

```css
   var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"#c000ff");
grd.addColorStop(0.13,"#c000ff");
grd.addColorStop(1,"#ff53c8");

ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

https://codepen.io/vadim-huva/pen/GadGpv

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985498/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-canvas-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/985757#985757

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял и вам нужен способ сделать прямоугольник с закругленными краями то легче всего это сделать с помощью функции [ctx.arcTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arcTo), которая принимает пять параметров:

x1 - Координата первой опорной точки по оси x.
y1 - Координата первой опорной точки по оси y.
x2 - Координата второй опорной точки по оси x.
y2 - Координата второй опорной точки по оси y.
radius - радиус дуги.

Прямая от текущей точки до x1,y1 - первая касательная.
Прямая от точки x1,y1 до x2,y2 - вторая касательная.
Эти две касательные оформляют дугу, а пятый парметр служит радиусом окружности, на которой усекается дуга.

Для вашего кода подойдет такая функция (не рекомендую использовать так как нет ни одной проверки и при неправильных значениях можете получить непредсказуемый результат):

```
function fillRoundedRect(ctx, x, y, w, h, r){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x + (w /2), y);
            ctx.arcTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + (h / 2), r);
            ctx.arcTo(x + w, y + h, x + (w / 2), y + h, r);
            ctx.arcTo(x, y + h, x, y + (h / 2), r);
            ctx.arcTo(x, y, x + (w / 2), y, r);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
}
```

x - координата верхней левой точки прямоугольника по оси х.
у - координата верхней левой точки прямоугольника по оси у.
w - длина прямоугольника.
h - высота прямоугольника.
r - радиус скругления краев.

В общем ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"#c000ff");
    grd.addColorStop(0.13,"#c000ff");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"#ff53c8");
    
    function fillRoundedRect(ctx, x, y, w, h, r){
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(x + (w /2), y);
     ctx.arcTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + (h / 2), r);
     ctx.arcTo(x + w, y + h, x + (w / 2), y + h, r);
     ctx.arcTo(x, y + h, x, y + (h / 2), r);
     ctx.arcTo(x, y, x + (w / 2), y, r);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
   }
   
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    fillRoundedRect(ctx, 20, 20, 150, 100, 15);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.fillStyle=grd;
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```