# Ручное декодирование и отображение кадров VP8 на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, видео, decode, libvpx

Хочу реализовать кросс-браузерный веб-плеер для своей системы видео стриминга, в которой клиент отправляет серверу сырые VP8 кадры, а сервер отдаёт их браузеру по WebSocket-ам при подписке на соответствующее событие.

Для выполнения задачи нашёл в сети реализацию vpx_decoder на JS ([dixie.js](https://github.com/dominikhlbg/vp8-webm-javascript-decoder)), которая, судя по отзывам в сети, у людей работает, но у меня почему-то изображение искажённое. Ниже приведу код, в котором получаемый с сервера видео-контент направляется на рендер как через этот скрипт, так и через свою обёртку над HTML5 video (для сравнения):

```
<script>
    // For canvas redner...
    let decoder = new vp8_decoder_ctx();
    let got_key = false;
    let cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
    cnv.width = 1280;
    cnv.height = 532;
    document.body.appendChild(cnv);
    let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
    var imgData = ctx.createImageData(cnv.width, cnv.height);

    // Image format conversion and support functions
    function clapm_byte(value) { return(value>255) ? 255 : ((value<0)?0:value); }
    function R(y, u, v) { return clapm_byte( (298 * y + 409 * v + 128)           >> 8); }
    function G(y, u, v) { return clapm_byte( (298 * y - 100 * u - 208 * v + 128) >> 8); }
    function B(y, u, v) { return clapm_byte( (298 * y + 516 * u + 128)           >> 8); }
    function I420toBGR(width, height, stride, y, u, v, out){
        let shift = -1;
        let half_stride = stride/2;
        let p_y, p_u, p_v;
        let bgr = out.data;
        for(let h = 0; h < height; ++h){
            for(let w = 0; w < width; ++w){
                p_y = y[h   * stride      + w  ] -  16;
                p_u = u[h/2 * half_stride + w/2] - 128;
                p_v = v[h/2 * half_stride + w/2] - 128;

                bgr[++shift] = B(p_y, p_u, p_v);
                bgr[++shift] = G(p_y, p_u, p_v);
                bgr[++shift] = R(p_y, p_u, p_v);
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(out, 0, 0);
    }

    // wrapper for stream object (for render in video tag)
    class MediaIO{
        constructor(){
            this.id = null;
            this.key = null;
            this.media = null;
            this.muxer = null;
        }
        Match(data){
            if (!this.id) return false;
            if (this.id.length !== data.length) return false;
            for(let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) if (data[i] !== this.id.charCodeAt(i)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    };

    // WebSocket packet handling procedure
    function HandlePacket(data, pool){
        let cxpf = new cxp_frame; // custom protocol to exchange with stream server
        let opcode = cxpf.parse(new Uint8Array(data));
        const stream = (cxp_stream | cxp_user | cxp_time | cxp_data);
        for(let i = 0; i < pool.length; ++i){
            let object = pool[i];
            if (!object.Match(cxpf.user)) continue;
            switch(opcode){
                case stream | object.key:{
                    let is_key_frame = (0x8000 & cxpf.time) > 0;
                    // cxpf.data - is a raw VP8 frame produced on С++ by calling vpx_codec_encode and vpx_codec_get_cx_data from libvpx

                    // Decoding in HTML5 video tag with manual EBML markup
                    object.muxer.Push(cxpf.data, is_key_frame);

                    // Manual decoding raw VP8 using dixie.js to draw on canvas
                    if (!got_key){
                        if (is_key_frame) got_key = true;
                        else break;
                    }
                    if (VPX_CODEC_OK === vp8_dixie_decode_frame(decoder, cxpf.data, cxpf.data.length)){
                        let img = decoder.ref_frames[0].img;
                        I420toBGR(img.d_w, img.d_h, img.stride[0], img.planes[0], img.planes[1], img.planes[2], imgData);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case cxp_user:{
                    if (object.muxer) object.muxer.Reset();
                    console.log("User",cxpf.user, "disconnectd from stream server");
                    break;
                }
                case cxp_user | object.key:{
                    object.muxer = new Stream(object.media.device); // Custom EBML muxer
                    console.log("User",cxpf.user,"key",object.key, "registered at stream server");
                    break;
                }
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }

    let user = new cxp_frame;
    user.load(cxp_user,atob("<?php echo $stream_access;?>"));

    let screen = new MediaIO;
    screen.id = "<?php echo $user_id;?>";
    screen.key = cxp_screen;
    screen.media = new Display(1280, 720, 0, document.body, true); // Custom wrapper for video tag

    let Sources = Array();
    Sources.push(screen);

    let socket = new Network( // custom WebSocket wrapper
        "localhost",
        778,
        function(event) { HandlePacket(event.data, Sources); }
    );

    let option = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < Sources.length; ++i) option |= Sources[i].key;
    socket.Send(user.pack(option));
</script>
```

Выглядит это в браузере так (вверху рендер на Canvas через dixie.js, внизу тэг video):
[image: WebDecodeVP8.jpg]

То есть контент валидный, и HTML5 video его выводит нормально.
К сожалению реализация через HTML5 video не будет бросс-браузерной - в тот же Safari, например, VP8 не зашит и работать не будет. Поэтому пытаюсь разобраться с ручной реализацией декодера. Код перевода из I420 в BGR / RGB взял из проекта на C++, где он уже отлажен и давал корректные изображения.

Может кто уже пытался сделать подобное, подскажите пожалуйста что не так с ручным декодером или с его использованием в моём коде?

Comment: меня смущает кол-во каналов которые Вы заполняете в теле цикла  `for(let h = 0; h < height; ++h){for(let w = 0; w < width; ++w){`, их там должно быть 4 - `rgba`, запишите в четвертый всегда 255

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а HTML5 Canvas воспринимает RGBA??? Если так, то скорее всего Вы правы!

Comment: вот, посмотрите как я тут делаю - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983698/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, понятно. Картинка поменялась, но всё ещё искажена. Это наводит на мысль, что декодирование проходит корректно, но хромают сам рендер на canvas и конвертирование изображения. Спасибо, буду копать вэту сторону

Comment: если Вы скопируете байты после конвертации в сниппет чтобы воспроизвести неполадку - я попробую вместе с Вами

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в общем, я сделал на плюсах снимок экрана в сыром I420, записал на диск, в JS добавил строку `bgr[++shift] = 255;` в конце конверсии, подгрузил его в скрипт через PHP и попробовал разложить это изоброажение в RGBA - отрисовало на canvas корректно! Спасибо за подсказку! VP8 после декодирования всё ещё искажено, но тут уже буду разбираться с тем, что даёт декодер на выходе

Comment: обратите внимание что именно r g b, первый красный

Answer (score 1):

В общем, разобрался!

Ошибка была в том, какие параметры изображения после декодирования использовались. Объект изображения имеет параметры ширины (`h`) и высоты (`w`), полученные при декодировании, а так же эти же параметры для отображения (`d_h` и `d_w` соответственно). Прогонять через конвертер форматов нужно именно параметры декодирования, а не отображения, так как они различаются. В результате конвертер переписал так:

```
function I420toRGBA(vp8, canvas){
    // Change display region on the fly
    if (canvas.width !== vp8.d_w) canvas.width = vp8.d_w;
    if (canvas.height !== vp8.d_h) canvas.height = vp8.d_h;

    let dif_w = (vp8.w - vp8.d_w) / 2;
    let dif_h = (vp8.h - vp8.d_h) / 2;

    let half_stride = vp8.w/2;
    let half_h, half_w;
    let p_y, p_u, p_v;

    let shift_u = vp8.img_data.length / 6 * 4;
    let shift_v = vp8.img_data.length / 6 * 5;

    let i = -1;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let out = ctx.createImageData(vp8.w, vp8.h);
    for(let h = 0; h < vp8.h; ++h){
        half_h = parseInt(h/2);
        for(let w = 0; w < vp8.w; ++w){
            p_y = vp8.img_data[h                * vp8.w       + w     ] -  16;
            half_w = parseInt(w/2);
            p_u = vp8.img_data[shift_u + half_h * half_stride + half_w] - 128;
            p_v = vp8.img_data[shift_v + half_h * half_stride + half_w] - 128;

            out.data[++i] = R(p_y, p_u, p_v);
            out.data[++i] = G(p_y, p_u, p_v);
            out.data[++i] = B(p_y, p_u, p_v);
            out.data[++i] = 255; // A
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(out, -dif_w, -dif_h, 0, 0, vp8.w, vp8.h);
}
```

вызывается так:

```
if (VPX_CODEC_OK === vp8_dixie_decode_frame(decoder, cxpf.data, cxpf.data.length))
    I420toRGBA(decoder.ref_frames[0].img, canvas);
```

В результате получил следующий профит:

1. Возможность воспроизводить стрим в любом браузере;
2. Отсутствие артефактов декодирования в отличие от HTML5 video при покадровом декодировании (без буферизации webm кластера на сервере) - то есть видео поток в реальном времени без глюков!
3. Отсутствие необходимости упаковывать кадры в EBML элементы для "понимания" их тегом video, так как декодируются сырые VP8 фреймы и тут же идут на рендер (единственное, нужно сопровождать кадр информацией о том, является ли он ключевым).

Спасибо *Stranger in the Q* за подсказку по RGBA в HTML5 canvas.